# Multiple projects for one domain nginx

Tags: symfony, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I need to setup two projects under one domain(react+symfony), here is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.ltd;
    rewrite_log on;
    root /var/www/frontend;

    access_log      /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;

    location / {
        index /index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        alias  /var/www/backend;
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
            internal;
        }
    }
}
```

root / works fine so static index.html I'm getting okay without any issues. but symfony application for /api throws an error(403 Forbidden) in nginx error.log:

`32349 open() "/var/www/frontend/index.php"`

For some reason alias ignored, what i'm doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The `location` and the `alias` values should both end with a `/` or neither end with a `/`. The last parameter of the `try_files` statement is a URI, so you need to include the `/api/` prefix.

For example:

```
location /api/ {
    alias  /var/www/backend/;
    try_files $uri /api/index.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;      
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }
}
```

Also, add a `try_files` statement to the nested `location` block to [avoid passing uncontrolled requests to PHP](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php). The correct value for `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is `$request_filename` which works with either `root` or `alias`.

Comment: changes made as you suggested but error still almost the same just changed path:
**33293 open() "/var/www/frontend/api" failed (2: No such file or directory)**
so seems nginx tries to access frontend directory instead of specified in alias **backend**